# Accord.Video.FFMPEG.VideoFileWriter writes different data from the input data

Tags: c#, .net, video, ffmpeg, accord.net

I'm working on project that encrypting video frames using RC4 algorithm and save these frames in playable video file.

I used a package named Accord.Video.FFMPEG. This package has a classes (VideoFileReader, & VideoFileWriter) that reads and writes video frames.

The first step is reads the video:

```
VideoHandler v = new VideoHandler();
OpenFileDialog newimag = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (newimag.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textfile = newimag.FileName;
            picbox.ImageLocation = textfile;
            status1.Text = "loaded";
            //MessageBox.Show("your video file have been loaded seccufly"); // is an idea for viwing message 

        }
    bytedata = v.ReadAllFrameBytes(textfile);
```

The second step is encrypting the frames of video:

```
byte[] bn = new byte[bytedata.Length];// new array to hold the encryptred file

        bn = Encrypt(bytedata, ba);
```

The last step is saving the encrypted frames:

```
v.WriteFramesData(newfilepath, bn);
```

My encrypting algorithm is encrypting and decrypting the cipher with same algorithm and key.

These stpes works on Text, and Images files, but when I use it on video I can't restore the encrypted video. After some testings,  I found that VideoFileWriter dosn't write the same input frames. Whyyyyyyy?

Here is my VideoFileHandler I made it:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Drawing.Imaging;
 using System.IO;
 using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;
 namespace imgtobyt_1_in_c
 {
class VideoHandler
{
    public List<byte[]> data;
    public byte[] imagedata;
    public int Height, Width;
    public byte[] ReadAllFrameBytes(string FileName)
    {
        // create instance of video reader
        VideoFileReader reader = new VideoFileReader();
        // open video file
        reader.Open(FileName);
        Height = reader.Height;
        Width = reader.Width;

        data = new List<byte[]>();
        // read video frames
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) //change 100 to reader.FrameCount
        {
            Bitmap videoFrame = reader.ReadVideoFrame();
            byte[] framebytes = GetBytesFromFrame(videoFrame);
            data.Add(framebytes);
            // dispose the frame when it is no longer required
            videoFrame.Dispose();
        }
        reader.Close();
        imagedata = new byte[data.Count * data[0].Length];
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            byte[] d = data[i];
            for (int x = 0; x < d.Length; x++)
            {
                imagedata[c] = d[x];
                c++;
            }
        }
        return imagedata;
    }

    public byte[] GetBytesFromFrame(Bitmap Frame)
    {
        LockBitmap lockBitmap = new LockBitmap(Frame);
        lockBitmap.LockBits();

        byte[] framebytes = new byte[Frame.Width * Frame.Height * 3];
        int z = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < lockBitmap.Height; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < lockBitmap.Width; y++)
            {
                Color Pixel = lockBitmap.GetPixel(y, x);
                framebytes[z] = Pixel.R;
                z++;
                framebytes[z] = Pixel.G;
                z++;
                framebytes[z] = Pixel.B;
                z++;
            }

        lockBitmap.UnlockBits();
        return framebytes;
        //using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        //{
        //    Frame.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        //    return stream.ToArray();
        //}
    }

    public Bitmap GetFrameFromBytes(byte[] Framebytes, ref int offset, int Width, int Height)
    {
        Bitmap Frame = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        LockBitmap lockBitmap = new LockBitmap(Frame);
        lockBitmap.LockBits();
        for (int x = 0; x < Height; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < Width; y++)
            {
                Color Pixel = Color.FromArgb(Framebytes[offset], Framebytes[offset + 1], Framebytes[offset + 2]); offset += 3;
                lockBitmap.SetPixel(y, x, Pixel);
            }

        lockBitmap.UnlockBits();

        return Frame;
        //Bitmap bmp;
        //using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Framebytes))
        //{
        //    bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
        //}
        //return bmp;
    }

    public void WriteFramesData(string FileName, byte[] data)
    {
        // create instance of video writer
        VideoFileWriter writer = new VideoFileWriter();
        // create new video file
        writer.Open(FileName, Width, Height);

        int offset = 0;
        // write video frames
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            // create a bitmap to save into the video file
            Bitmap Frame = GetFrameFromBytes(data, ref offset, Width, Height);
            writer.WriteVideoFrame(Frame);
        }
        writer.Close();
    }
}
 }
```

Please, I need to make this works.

Comment: If you are trying to encrypt, encode, decode then decrypt a frame, then you need to make sure your encode process is lossless. Not sure what VideoFileWriter defaults to, but you can try to set the codec to rawvideo.

Comment: What is codec?? is related to some of compression technique?

Comment: Codec is the compression "technique". Raw means there is no compression. You can try the others, but I didn't notice a way to configure them as lossless.